# SQL query to get the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Table 1**

```
CutomerID    Salary   
1             2000              
2             3000              
3             4000      
4             6000      
5             5220
```

**Table 2**

```
  DeptID  DeptNam
  1       IT                           
  2       Finance                
  3       Marketing
```

**Table 3**

```
  CustomerID    DeptID
    1            1
    2            1 
    3            2
    4            3
    5            3
```

Question : find the people with highest salary in each dept

Rows to return :    `CustomerID     DeptName     Salary`

Question : find the people with highest salary in each dept

Rows to return :    `CustomerID     DeptName     Salary`

Can anybody help me out how to write the SQL query for this?

Comment: Smells as homework. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry only SQL... I am just trying my best to learn like this way to get different asnwers..

Comment: please provide an example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT T1.*, T3.DeptID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY T3.DeptID ORDER BY T1.Salary DESC) RN
    FROM Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table3 AS T3
    ON T1.CustomerId = T3.CustomerId
)
SELECT A.CustomerId, B.DeptName, A.Salary
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.DeptID = B.DeptID
WHERE RN = 1
```

You should take into account that if the max salary per department is duplicated, then this query will return more than one result per department.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL-Server 2005 and beyond, using a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

Find the people with highest salary in each dept

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.CustomerID ,t2.DeptName, t1.Salary , SalaryRank = 
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t2.DeptID ORDER BY t1.Salary DESC)
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.CustomerID=t3.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.DeptID=t2.DeptID
)
SELECT CustomerID, DeptName, Salary FROM CTE
WHERE SalaryRank = 1
```

Here's the **sql-fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ff1/2/0

---

If you want to return multiple customers if they have the same salary, use [`RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead of `ROW_NUMBER` as @Lamak has suggested.

Here are the differences: http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.de/2008/10/difference-between-rownumber-rank-and.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.customerid,
       c.deptnam,
       a.salary
FROM   table1 a
JOIN   table3 b ON a.customerid = b.customerid
JOIN   table2 c ON b.deptid = c.deptid
JOIN
(
    SELECT   aa.deptid, MAX(bb.salary) AS maxsalary
    FROM     table3 aa
    JOIN     table1 bb ON aa.customerid = bb.customerid
    GROUP BY aa.deptid
) d ON a.salary = d.maxsalary AND c.deptid = d.deptid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE cust(CutomerID int,Salary float)

INSERT INTO cust
VALUES(1,2000),(2,3000),(3,4000),(4,6000),(5,5220)

CREATE TABLE dept(DeptID int,DeptNam varchar(10))

INSERT INTO dept
VALUES(1,'IT'),(2,'Finance'),(3,'Marketing') 

CREATE TABLE custDept(CustomerID int,DeptID int)

INSERT INTO custDept
VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,3)

select a.CutomerID,a.DeptNam,b.sal  from 

(select c.CutomerID ,d.DeptID,c.Salary,d.DeptNam  from cust c inner join custDept cd on 
c.CutomerID = cd.CustomerID 
inner join dept d
on cd.DeptID =d.DeptID) a

inner join 
(select d.DeptID ,MAX(c.Salary) as sal  from cust c inner join custDept cd on 
c.CutomerID = cd.CustomerID 
inner join dept d
on cd.DeptID =d.DeptID
group by  d.DeptID) b

on a.DeptID = b.DeptID and a.Salary = b.sal
```